# how to reverse the extracted entry after modification

Tags: csv, stream

I am working with csv file having very large dataset. while reading file i had extracted 4th place(BALANCE) ';' separated numeric value from each rows  through while loop iteration. and make a list of Double after some mathematical calculation(here incremented).

now I want to store this list of Double in reverse order(from end to beginning).as its original position(here 4th  place).example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String filename = "abc.csv";
    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();

    File file = new File(filename);
         Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
        inputStream.next();

        while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
            String data = inputStream.next();         
            String[] values = data.split(";");
            double BALANCE = Double.parseDouble(values[1]);
            BALANCE = BALANCE + 1;  
            ListIterator li = list.listIterator(list.size());
            while (li.hasPrevious()) {
                values[1] = String.valueOf(li.previous());                 }
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }     }
```

Comment: why are you using Double to store int values in a List..?

Comment: actually here for simplify the code I just show increment operation. but in some mathematical calculation I will include its mean and standard deviation there. so its necessary for me to use a Double.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Collections.reverse`. Example `Collections.reverse(list);`

Comment: I tried Collections.reverse(list); but it is print in original position I don't know why?

Comment: I think you issue is in your printing logic. If you could post your code it would be better to correct.